# How to read not my own bucket with python and boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I know bucket name, I have access to it, I can browse it by web and by awscli.

How access it by Python's boto3? All examples assume accessing my own buckets:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

How to reach other's bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to someone else's bucket and you know the name of that bucket you can access it like

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('some-bucket-i-have-access-to')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

Comment: How to set region? I was to set region to access via AWSCLI?

Comment: boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-west-2')